# Adding validation messages to MVC classes generated by Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, frameworks, entity

I am starting an MVC project and designing my DB in EF, which means I design the tables, and VS creates the classes I need to access them.

The problem is, I want to make use of attributes like `DisplayName`, `Required` and generating validation error messages ( including specifying rules to validate ).

As far as I can see, the classes are recreated every time I change my DB, so I can't really add them to the classes.  Is there another way to do this once and have it persist ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you would use the [`MetadataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx) attribute and link your entity to a type where you'll set the validation attributes.

Something like this for an Entity `Person`:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Person_Validation))]//<<link to metadata class
public partial class Person//<<<Your real entity class
{//this is in a separate file.
  //note =>partial. There's nothing in this class
}
public class Person_Validation//the validations go here.
{
        [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage="Name is required"), Required]
        [DisplayName("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```